# Custom layout changes are not visible on frontend in mangeto 2

Tags: magento2, layout

I have added custom layout with 4 columns in custom theme.
This is my layouts.xml in E:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\design\frontend\vendor\custom-theme\Magento_Theme\layouts.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<page_layouts xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/PageLayout/etc/layouts.xsd">

    <layout id="4columns">
      <label translate="true">Home columns</label>
    </layout>
</page_layouts>
```

This is my 4columns.xml located in \app\design\frontend\vendor\custom-theme\Magento_Theme\page_layout\4columns.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_layout.xsd">
<update handle="3columns"/>

  <referenceContainer name="columns">
      <container name="fouth.column" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="fourth-column" after="-">
      </container>
   </referenceContainer>
</layout>
```

This is my default.xml located in \app\design\frontend\vendor\custom-theme\Magento_Theme\layout\default.xml

```
<page  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="logo">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="logo_file" xsi:type="string">images/custom-logo.jpg</argument>
            <argument name="logo_img_width" xsi:type="number">100</argument> 
            <argument name="logo_img_height" xsi:type="number">100</argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
    <referenceContainer name="fouth.column">
          <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="home-page-block">
             <arguments>
              <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">home-page-block</argument>
             <arguments>
          </block>
    </referenceContainer>

</body>
</page>
```

From admin panel, for Home page , I have selected Home columns Layout in design tab of PAges.But still I can't see these changes on front though I have cleared cache so many times.

I am not getting any error also.Can anyone suggest what's wrong here?
I am newbie to magento.So I am not understanding .

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the other question you have not closed your `<arguments>` tag in your default.xml, your last `<arguments>` should be `</arguments>`.

The rest of the code should work, try adding a template file instead of a static block just in case the problem is with the static block.